# AKKA Message delivery fails

Tags: java, akka, message, dead-letter

I have the following hierachy in my actor system

Master actor

```
 if (msg instanceof doMajortTask) {
    ActorRef slave = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(slave.class));
            slave.tell(new doSubTask(), getSelf());

//tell parent job is complete

}

if (msg instanceof differentMessage) {
// do something else 
}
```

Slave Actor

```
if (msg instanceof doSubTask) {
            getSender().tell(new differentMessage(), getSelf());
        }
    }
```

Master Actor is created per request, for first request this hierarchy works properly, for second request the '`differentMessage` remains undelivered"

Note that there are many message exchanges btween these two actors. But I havent added them because they have nothing different. Can the number of messages be an issue?

Does the master actor die based on what? Does too many context switching netween actors lead to this?

Comment: Post the full implementation. Or stripped out. This is insufficient to tell you exactly what could go wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have update the question